# How do I convert recursion to iteration for this code that converts scipy tree object to json?

Tags: python, json, recursion, scipy, iteration

I am trying to convert a Scipy tree object (returned from scipy's to_tree method) to json so that I can visualize a dendrogram in D3. Basically, I am trying to do the same thing as:

[scipy dendrogram to json for d3.js tree visualisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964266/scipy-dendrogram-to-json-for-d3-js-tree-visualisation)

The answer suggested by mdml works perfectly, but his answer uses recursion in the add_node method. When data is large, it would throw `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

So I am trying to implement add_node by using iteration instead of recursion.

The following code is what I have tried, but it doesn't give me the correct result. After each iteration, the 'info' dictionary must be assigned to the list 'children', but the problem is I don't know how to move on to the innermost level of children after each iteration. As shown in the expected result below, there is 'children' inside 'children' and so on.

So what should I do to assign 'info' to the correct 'children' after each iteration?

```
import pandas as pd 
import scipy.spatial
import scipy.cluster
import numpy as np
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from functools import reduce

geneExp = {'genes' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],
       'exp1': [-2.2, 5.6, 0.9, -0.23, -3, 0.1],
       'exp2': [5.4, -0.5, 2.33, 3.1, 4.1, -3.2]
          }
df = pd.DataFrame( geneExp )
dataMatrix = np.array( df[['exp1', 'exp2']] )
distMat = scipy.spatial.distance.pdist( dataMatrix )

clusters = scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage(distMat, method='single')
T = scipy.cluster.hierarchy.to_tree( clusters , rd=False )
D = dict(children=[], name="Root1")
Nodes = [T]
while(1):
    for node in Nodes:
        if node.is_leaf()==True:
            info = dict(node_id=node.id,children=[])
            D['children'].append(info)
        else:
            if len(D['children'])>0:
                info = dict(node_id=node.id,children=[])
                D['children'].append(info)
                T1 = T.get_right()
                T2 = T.get_left()
                newNodes = [T1,T2]
                D = D['children'][0]   ### ???
                Nodes = newNodes
            else:
                info = dict(node_id=node.id,children=[])
                D['children'].append(info)
                T1 = T.get_right()
                T2 = T.get_left()
                newNodes = [T1,T2]
                D = D['children'][0]   ### ???
                Nodes = newNodes
```

This is the expected result.

```
{'children': [{'node_id': 10,
   'children': [{'node_id': 5, 'children': []},
    {'node_id': 9,
     'children': [{'node_id': 1, 'children': []},
      {'node_id': 8,
       'children': [{'node_id': 6,
         'children': [{'node_id': 2, 'children': []},
          {'node_id': 3, 'children': []}]},
        {'node_id': 7,
         'children': [{'node_id': 0, 'children': []},
          {'node_id': 4, 'children': []}]}]}]}]}],
 'name': 'Root1'}
```